# Select All / DeSelect All Options in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to do a select all, deselect all with jQuery Mobile. It seems trivial, but been pulling my hear out all day about this. This is what it looks like:

Here's the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm89P/2/)**.

[image]

```
<div data-role="page" id="one">
  <div data-role="content">
    <label for="sel">Select the Options</label>
    <select name="sel" id="sel" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="-1" selected>-All Brands-</option>
      <option value="1">Prod 1</option>
      <option value="2">Prod 2</option>
      <option value="3">Prod 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var arr = [];
$("#sel").live("change", function (event, ui) {
    var txt = $("#sel option:selected").text();
    if (txt.search("-All Brands-")) {

        $("#sel option").attr("selected", "selected");

    }
    else {
        $("#sel option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

    }
    $("#sel").selectmenu("refresh", true);
})
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff and can't get it just right.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Gm89P/6/ use `.prop("selected", true/false)`.

Comment: it fixes the all brands box but because that handler runs when the select box changes, clicking any other item doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the jquery mobile multi select only has a change event, as you probably read. So the only way I can think of is to store the state of the all brands item and then check if it's changed, and select or deselect all. Here's your JSFiddle with the changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gm89P/7/

like this:

```
var arr = [];
$("#sel").on("change", function (event, ui) {

    var allSelected = $("option:first", this).attr("selected");

    if (this.wasAllSelected && !allSelected) {
        $("#sel option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        this.wasAllSelected = allSelected;
    }
    else if (!this.wasAllSelected && allSelected) {
        $("#sel option").attr("selected", "selected");
        this.wasAllSelected = allSelected;
    }
    $("#sel").selectmenu("refresh", true);
})
```

Comment: Thanks Damon. This helps a lot. One thing I noticed was that if the "All Brands" option is defaulted to selected, then the next time you check off 1 option, it selects all.

Check out the Fiddle here to see what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/Gm89P/8/ - I just added the selected attribute to the option element.

Comment: if you default the all brands to selected you'll need to also change the default value of wasAllSelected to true so that it's in the same state as the checkbox. This isn't straightforward but one way to do it would be to test if this.wasAllSelected hasn't been initialised yet and if it hasn't, set it to true, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gm89P/10/
Note, if you default all brands to selected you really need to set them all to selected, otherwise they're out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to manipulate the classes you can do it manually like this:

```
// For de-selecting

$( '#yourSelectMenuId'  ).val( '' ).change();
$( '#yourSelectMenuId-listbox ul li a' ).removeClass( 'ui-checkbox-on' );
$( '#yourSelectMenuId-listbox ul li a' ).addClass( 'ui-checkbox-off' );
```

don't forget adding -listbox extension to your select menu id which jqm added automatically.